# how to create a bridge network with only wirless interface

Tags: wifi, kvm

im trying to install kvm in ubuntu,and when i build the virtual network,

```
$vim /etc/network/interfaces
...
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports wlp2s0
bridge_stp on
bridge_fd 0
...
```

systemctl restart networking && reboot

en... cloud not connect the wifi

and i knew that it worked on service computer ,because the device "wlp2s0" will connect to a Ethermet cables，but how does it work by using wirless device

Comment: virt-manager can create a bridge-type virtual network  successfully,and my laptop just got a wireless device

Comment: More context is needed. For example, it's usually not possible to use a bridge with wifi when used as a "client" (STA mode). It's only possible when used as an access point (your system is the AP providing the wifi service). Either the configuration won't tell something is wrong, but you can't use the result in the end, or the card will refuse to be in a bridge unless in 4 addr mode (details related to 3 vs 4 address mode  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header)

Comment: I took an old router, flashed it to dd-wrt, and set it up in "client bridge" mode. Then, I connected the PC to it via ethernet.

Comment: OK, I understand, the wireless network card and the wired network card are different. There must be something I need to know between them.
Another problem, when ubuntu installs kvm, if you only install virsh, do not install virt-manager, how to set up a virtual network. Or to put aside the virtual machine, how to set up a virtual network with a wireless network card?